# How to reduce memory usage when creating windows metro applications?

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I created a metro style app or windows 8,but on using that app my CPU memory usage is always going high,not a single byte is reduced after started running.I think this s because of not properly handling memory.Any body have suggestions for effective handling memory?

Comment: What do you mean by "high"?

Comment: memory usage is going  up...

Comment: Anybody having suggestions..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think windows rt handles memory on its own ... so no garbage collection or releasing.

I have a pretty memory intensive app and I find that the following really impacts memory:

1. lots of ui elements in XAML files
2. large predefined arrays (e.g., string[,] arr = new string[100,100])
3. not using [incremental loading](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2012/06/10/Metro-Incrementally-load-GridView-and-ListView-with-ISupportIncrementalLoading.aspx) and [ItemsControl](http://www.dutton.me.uk/2013/02/09/how-to-add-a-scrollviewer-to-an-itemscontrol-in-a-windows-store-app/)

If you provide more info about what your app contains/does the community can help you a bit more.

Comment: Yeah..My Application is certainly having lot of UI pages,Each of the pages is loaded by a request to web-service.Polling is also implemented,so every time the apps ui gets  updated.It uses a long running thread to send messages and receive response...

Comment: You may already be doing step 3 in my original response, but just in case I added a couple of links for incremental loading and items control.